# this, const is a reserved word reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I try to pass data from a parent component to a child with props. I tried to update inside this.State, outside the constructor and i get the error, this is a reserved word and then const is a reserved word Here is the code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class DoughnutChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        const { a } = this.props.percent_value;
        const { b } = (100 - this.props.percent_value);
        const { c }

      doughData: {
             type: 'doughnut',
           labels: ['Success'],
           data: {
          datasets: [
            {
              label: {c},
              data: [value1, value2],
              backgroundColor: ['#2698A1', '#F0F5F7']
            }
          ]
        }    
      };
    }
   render() {
        return (
          <div className="doughchart">
          <DoughnutChart
            data={{
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: [c],
                  data: [value1, value2],
                  backgroundColor: ['#2698A1', '#F0F5F7']
                }
              ]}}
            width={140}
            height={140}
            options={{
              cutoutPercentage: 80
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default DoughChart;
```

Also i try to declare as const this.props so to bypass the reserved word problem and then i get error 
  c' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 15:  'value1' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 15:  'value2' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 36:  'value1' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 36:  'value2' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 51:  'DoughChart' is not defined

based on the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class DoughnutChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      doughData: {
        type: 'doughnut',
        labels: ['Success'],
        data: {
          datasets: [
            {
              label: {c},
              data: [value1, value2],
              backgroundColor: ['#2698A1', '#F0F5F7']
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {a} = this.props.percent_value;
    const {b} = 100 - this.props.percent_value;
    const {c} = this.props.label;

    return (
      <div className="doughchart">
        <DoughnutChart
          data={this.State.doughData}
          width={140}
          height={140}
          options={{
            cutoutPercentage: 80
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DoughChart;
```

How can i transfer correctly the props values of the array into the component through the this.State?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set `this.state` with invalid syntax.  That is a Javascript object, so you have to use key-value notation to add properties

```
this.state = {
    a: this.props.percent_value,
    b: 100 - this.props.percent_value
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but now it says that a, b, c are not defined

Comment: because you need to access them like `this.state.a` and `this.state.b`

Comment: so I type what you said and access them into the return method   `<DoughnutChart
          data={{
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: this.state.c,
                  data: [this.state.a, this.state.b],
                  backgroundColor: ['#2698A1', '#F0F5F7']
                }
              ]
            }
          }}
/>` but now it says Cannot read property 'percent_value' of undefined for a: this.props.doughnutData.percent_value is there something not working with this.props inside the this.state ?

Comment: look at all the places you're accessing those variables.  I've showed you the correct way.  its up to you to apply the answer